# How to configure javadb in eclipse(part2)?

Tags: java, database, eclipse, derby

this is the continuation of my previous question [How to configure javadb in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909305/how-to-configure-javadb-in-eclipse). I was able to made some changes on my code but now it is giving me this error -> **ERROR: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect**. Hope you guys can help me with this one.

Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/CoffeeDB;create=true";

    try{
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String sql = ("CREATE TABLE Coffee(Description CHAR(25),ProdNum CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,Price DOUBLE)");
        stmt.execute(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO Coffee VALUES('Bolivian Dark','14-001',8.95)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO Coffee VALUES('Bolivian Medium','14-002',8.95)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO Coffee VALUES('Brazilian Dark','15-001',7.95)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO Coffee VALUES('Brazilian Medium','15-002',7.95)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO Coffee VALUES('Brazilian Decaf','15-003',8.55)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO Coffee VALUES('Central American Dark','16-001',9.95)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO Coffee VALUES('Central American Medium','16-002',9.95)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO Coffee VALUES('Sumatra Dark','17-001',7.95)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO Coffee VALUES('Sumatra Decaf','17-002',8.95)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO Coffee VALUES('Sumatra Medium','17-003',7.95)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO Coffee VALUES('Sumatra Organic Dark','17-004',11.95)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO Coffee VALUES('Kona Medium','18-001',18.45)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO Coffee VALUES('Kona Dark','18-002',18.45)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO Coffee VALUES('French Roast Dark','19-001',9.65)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO Coffee VALUES('Galapagos Medium','20-001',6.85)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO Coffee VALUES('Guatemalan Dark','21-001',9.95)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO Coffee VALUES('Guatemalan Decaf','21-002',10.45)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO Coffee VALUES('Guatemalan Medium','21-003',9.95)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        String sqlStatement = "SELECT Description FROM Coffee";
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStatement);

        System.out.println("Coffees found in the Database");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");

        while(result.next()){
            System.out.println(result.getString("Description"));
        }

        conn.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Hey @Pearl, which OS?

Comment: @James Jithin - you mean operating system right? its windows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been trying with your current code and found that the exception happens when the server is not being started. The way to solve this is start the server in a simple way:

Go to the lib folder in the extracted folder of derby server download over command prompt. For me it was as follows:

```
C:\>cd opt\db-derby-10.11.1.1-lib\lib

C:\opt\db-derby-10.11.1.1-lib\lib>java -jar derbyrun.jar server start
Sat Oct 03 16:26:29 IST 2015 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Sat Oct 03 16:26:29 IST 2015 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.11.1.1 - (1616546) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527
```

There is a different way by which you can start the server in Eclipse. You would need to install plugin and then start the server. The following references should help you:

[Derby Plugin How To](https://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_howto.html)

[Getting Started with Derby Plugin for Eclipse](https://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/start_toc.html#Getting+Started+with+the+Derby+plug-ins+for+Eclipse)

Comment: finally it worked..i was able to download the plugins and rearrange the environment variables and java build path..

Comment: @Pearl, congrats! Happy coding. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950996/cant-connect-to-derby-in-eclipse?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141733/javadb-having-port-connection-error?rq=1